# Salesforce Hot Network Question

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

Has at any time a question on Salesforce Stack Exchange made it into the list of [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot)?

I very much doubt it - but if so, what question was this?

Comment: I believe [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/361731/is-it-more-efficient-to-use-a-map-and-call-get-or-use-a-set-and-call-contai/361740#361740) did (see Derek's comment on it). Not sure how frequently it happens or if there's a way to query that.

Comment: It has happened many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [query which questions have been on the list via the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286986).

I linked to such a query for Salesforce Stack exchange **[here](https://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/revision/1561849/1908679/hot-network-questions)**.

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much, Adrian! Although I must admit the frequency doesn't match my experience. Maybe Stack Exchange forgot to have a "Duration" (maybe often in the area of minutes) field for a reason?!

Comment: Maybe someone out there has done the math, but if you're not regularly viewing all, I'm not surprised.

Comment: If you're interested, I see this for what is [considered "hot"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/what-are-the-criteria-for-questions-to-be-selected-for-hot-network-questions).